# Signalr: how to stop/close one connection directly without go through re-connection process

Tags: angular, signalr

In my Angular project, I use Signalr to get real-time data as following:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');
contosoChatHubProxy.on('addContosoChatMessageToPage', function(userName, message) {
    console.log(userName + ' ' + message);
});
connection.start()
    .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id); })
    .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not connect'); });

connection.stateChanged((state: SignalR.StateChanged) => {
  if (state.newState === ConnectionState.Disconnected) {
      connection.start()
  }
});
```

The above code is not 100% same as my code. But the logic is same, start the connection, and set the re-connection logic as well.

In my project, based on some cases I need to reset the connection, which means I need to close the existing connection and start a new one.

I tried `connection.stop()`, but since there is re-connection logic here, the connection will first become disconnect status and automatically restart again.

Is there any other API from SignalR client side, can meet my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag for whenever you call `connection.stop()`.

Let's call it `manually_stopped`

And in your `stateChanged` handler add a check for `manually_stopped`

Wherever you call `connection.stop()`, do this:

```
fucntion_to_close_connection(){
  manually_stopped = 1
  connection.stop()
}
```

```
connection.stateChanged((state: SignalR.StateChanged) => {
  if (state.newState === ConnectionState.Disconnected && manually_stopped == 0) {
      connection.start()
  }
});
```